# Adding row to table with Jquery error [object HTMLSpanElement]

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4

I am trying to add the value of a Modal to a table but the error appears Adding row to table with Jquery error [object HTMLSpanElement], when I click on register.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".add").click(function(){
        //var name = $("#nomeoferta").val();
        var name = document.getElementById('nomeoferta');
        var lastname = $("#descontooferta").val();
        var lastname = $("#ativodesde").val();
        var markup = "<tr><td></td><td>" + nomeoferta + "</td><td>" + descontooferta + "</td><td></td><td>" + ativodesde + "</td></tr>";
        $("#dataTable").append(markup);
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
      <!-- Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
            aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Cadastro de Novas Ofertas</h5>

                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group mb-3">
                        <span class="input-group-text" id="nomeoferta">Nome da Oferta</span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Nome da Oferta"
                            aria-label="Username" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group mb-3">
                        <span class="input-group-text" id="descontooferta">Desconto de: </span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control col-md-4" placeholder="Desconto"
                            aria-label="Desconto" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" type="number">
                        <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon2">%</span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="input-group mb-3">
                        <span class="input-group-text" id="ativodesde">Ativo desde</span>
                        <input type="date" class="form-control col-md-4" placeholder="Desconto"
                            aria-label="Desconto" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" type="number">

                    </div>


                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary add">Cadastrar</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Modal -->
```

[image: Modal]

[image: error]

Comment: When you see `[object HTMLSpanElement]` (or `[object Object]`) it means you're trying to convert an object/htmlspanelement intro a string.  You need to use a relevant property, maybe `.innerText`.  You *probably* wanted `var name = $("#nomeoferta").text();` if it's a `span` - but that variable isn't used in the *code provided*

Comment: @freedomn I tried several options, like var name = $ ("#nomeoferta"). Text, var name = $ ("# descontooferta"). Val; and etc.

What I really want is to take the data from the modal and write it in the rs table

Comment: `$("#span_id").text()` - lowercase, no space, with `()`

Comment: Although, looking closer, you have the `id` in the `span` `<span id="nomeoferta"...` - **move** it to the `input` `<input type='text' id="nomeoferta"...`  and use `$("#nomeoferta").val()`

Comment: function(n){var r,e,i,t=this[0];return arguments.length?(i=b(n),this.each(function(e){var t;1===this.nodeType&&(null==(t=i?n.call(this,e,E(this).val()):n)?t="":"number"==typeof t?t+="":Array.isArray(t)&&(t=E.map(t,function(e){return null==e?"":e+""})),(r=E.valHooks[this.type]||E.valHooks[this.nodeName.toLowerCase()])&&"set"in r&&void 0!==r.set(this,t,"value")||(this.value=t))})):t?(r=E.valHooks[t.type]||E.valHooks[t.nodeName.toLowerCase()])&&"get"in r&&void 0!==(e=r.get(t,"value"))?e:"string"==typeof(e=t.value)?e.replace(ut,""):null==e?"":e:void 0}

Comment: Looks like again missing the `()`, but otherwise that means nothing

Comment: I missed the (), now I corrected it and it worked, if you want, put as an answer that I accept there, thank you very much.